# Is there any way to do a fast inaccurate count(*) with a where condition in myisam?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a table with 150 mln rows with such a definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `done` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `done` (`done`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=154505834 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`select count(*) from tasks where done = 1;` takes 20 seconds.

I don't care about the exact value too much: no problem to have it rounded to the nearest million. Is there a way to make the less query less accurate, but faster?

Comment: Add an index on `done` like that: `ALTER TABLE task ADD INDEX (done ) ;`

Comment: @ojovirtual Key is a synonym for index. [see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) `KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.`

Comment: @BenSwinburne oopsss, sorry pal, didn't see that!

Comment: If the data is random, then you can calculate the `probability` of the done=1, then the `probability * totalnum` would get you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've tried indexing and it can't be sped up, and upgrading hardware (RAM, SSD, whatever) isn't an option, consider some form of "architecture" approach: e.g. record a nightly snapshot of the count that you can lookup throughout the next day? Is this accurate enough?

Edit: or, hourly, or whatever frequency works!